# Php Cant insert Json data with apostrophe to database

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I have some json data that i am retrieving from an external url. I am storing the data but It seems that the values that have an apostrophe "Tes't2" is being skipped over. I have seen people say to quote escape this, but i am not sure how to do this. I'm a noobie. Thanks!

Here is my php

```
$filename = "http://www.someurl.com/data.json";  
$data = file_get_contents($filename);  
$array = json_decode($data, true);

 foreach($array as $row)  
 {  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO table_popular_items(rank, name) VALUES (
      '".$row["rank"]."', 
      '".$row["name"]."'
      )";       
      mysqli_query($connect, $sql);       
 }
```

Here is the data.json

```
[
    {
        "rank": 1,
        "name": "Test1"
    },
    {
        "rank": 2,
        "name": "Tes't2"

    },
    {
        "rank": 3,
        "name": "Test3"
    }
```

]

Comment: Use prepared queries, don't concatenate variables into a query. see here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `table_popular_items`(`rank`, `name`) VALUES (
  '".$row["rank"]."', 
  '".addslashes($row["name"])."'
  )";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $YOUR_VARIABLE);` should work.

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php